# Invalid enum value '' cannot be deserialized into type

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service having an enum defined as -

```
public enum Operator
{ 
    Equals,
    NotEquals,
    GreatherThan,
    LessThan
}
```

DataContract declared as -

```
[DataContract]
public class PropertyQuery
{
    [DataMember]
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Operator Operator { get; set; }        

    [DataMember]
    public string PropertyValue { get; set; }
}
```

OperationContract declared as -

```
[OperationContract]        
string GetClientData(string clientName, [Optional] PropertyQuery propertyQuery);
```

However when I send request for 'GetClientData()' using SoapUI with passing value only for first parameter 'clientName' and leaving blanks for 'propertyQuery' parameters -

```
  <tem:GetClientData>
     <tem:clientName>AV</tem:clientName>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <tem:propertyQuery>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <wcf:Operator></wcf:Operator>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <wcf:PropertyName></wcf:PropertyName>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <wcf:PropertyValue></wcf:PropertyValue>
     </tem:propertyQuery>
  </tem:GetClientData>
```

I get following message -

> *Invalid enum value '' cannot be deserialized into type 'WCFService2.Operator'. Ensure that the necessary enum values are present and are marked with EnumMemberAttribute attribute if the type has DataContractAttribute attribute.'*.

I know this error makes sense.
But how to make 'propertyQuery' as optional and thus 'Operator' as optional and get rid of this error.

Please guide.

Comment: What do you mean by leaving blanks, can you show the request?

Comment: updated with SoapUI request

Comment: @iniki how did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Do exactly as the error message tells you, and mark the enum members with the EnumMember attribute.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347875%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
[DataContract]  
public enum Operator  
{  
     [EnumMember]  
     Equals,  
     [EnumMember]  
     GreatherThan,  
     [EnumMember]  
     LessThan,  
     [EnumMember]  
     NotEquals,  
}
```

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue, but I have the EnumMember values in place. Even more strangely, I only get that error with certain values and not others, and it seems to be the very first value that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you're testing against the correct endpoint.